# Write does not produce a value issue

Tags: vb.net

Alright, I've managed to get a string containing HTML content inside of it, but I need to get into an `HTMLDocument` for parsing.

I've tested the following code, and I've been unable to get it to work through any of the variations I've tried.

```
    Dim webclient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim result As String = webclient.DownloadString(link)

    Dim htm As HtmlDocument

    htm = htm.Write(result)

    Dim sDD As Object
    sDD = htm.GetElementById("tag-sidebar")

    Dim IDD As Object
    IDD = htm.GetElementById("highres")
```

Currently it is telling me that `htm = htm.Write(result)` does not produce a value, so I'm sort of stumped.

I'm Currently using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Professional

Comment: Please do not change the question you are asking once you've received an answer.

Comment: Your original question about the Write method was answered by Dan-o. Now you've changed the code, and are asking something else.

Comment: The edit doesn't move the question along, it regresses it. `Write` is the correct method to use, the problem was just that it doesn't return a value. It modifies your instance of the `HtmlDocument` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error just indicates that the `Write` method does not produce a value.  In VB-speak that means `Write` is a *Sub*, not a *Function*.